# C# : Pdf file opens in a new window .. instead of opening within the form

Tags: c#

Here is the code snippet:

```
  public Documentation_File(String path, String name, Documentation_Option doc_option)
  {
      _doc_option = doc_option;
      InitializeComponent();
      WebBrowser web = new WebBrowser();
      web.Url = new Uri(path);
  }
```

Note path ==> path of a certain document.

I would like the pdf file to open inside the C# form itself. Instead it opens up in a new window.

Comment: How you are navigating to that page?

Comment: @"C:\Users\home\Documents\Details\abc.pdf" is the string that is being passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Acrobat is installed, you could try to load their ActiveX control into your form, and bypass the WebBrowser.

There are toolkits that can be used to show a PDF in a form:

Disclaimer: I work at Atalasoft: [DotImage Photo](http://atalasoft.com/photofree) is free and will give you a viewer component, and you can add on the [PDF Reader](http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/pdf-reader) for it to view PDF.

Comment: Hi Lou : thanks for the reply ... I was getting the class not registered exception.. tried to find a solution .. in vain .. thats why i switched to the web browser :(

Comment: Well ... No solution .. but managed to get the adobe part working . had to insert one line ... into an xml file ..  making  the target x86..